# Power BI secure embedded report login not working on some browsers (windows chrome)

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have created a secure embedded report (using the new method released in 2019) as specified below:
https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/easily-embed-secure-power-bi-reports-in-your-internal-portals-or-websites/

I created this in an html page using the supplied iframe.

It works fine on windows firefox and edge.  It does not work in windows chrome.

It works fine on mac chrome.  It does not work on mac safari.

It fails on windows chrome after opening a new tab and asking for the login details, this tab then closes and the power BI symbol in the embedded report just flashes like it is loading but it never finishes.
On Mac safari the login fails.  It looks like it gets caught in a loop of some kind.

I just want it working on windows chrome really.

I have tried clearing my complete browser cache, cookies, rebooting serveral times and allowing pop-ups with no luck.
It does not make a difference if I select "remember me" or not at the time of login.
I have the latest version of chrome.

**Does anyone know how to resolve this or if this is a know issue?**

Here is the embedded report.  You won't be able to access it but it may give you an idea of the issue:
https://fir-trial-66e3f.firebaseapp.com/embedded-report.html

I also can't log into the PBI community with this account so that may be related.  The account works fine logging in to PBI Service or desktop.  It is a PBI trial Pro account.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, i solved it by disabling the "Prevent Cross-Site Tracking" in Safari Settings. This worked for me and my clients. I hope it works for you too

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue in chrome. Solved it by enabling "Allow all cookies" in chrome settings.